# ajax accessing xml nodes

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

after an Ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
            //web service pubblico di prova
            url: "*web service*"       
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "xml", 

            processData: false,

            contentType: "text/xml",

            data: soapMessage, 
            success: function(soapResponse){
                //must access the xml tag HERE                   
             var ss= $(soapResponse);
             //like this i see all the xml
             alert(ss.text());  
              },
              error: function (request, status, error) {
                  alert(request);
                  alert(status);
                  alert(error);
              }
          });
    }
```

i've got an xml like this:

```
<ROOT>
<ElencoSoggettiTemplate>
<SoggettiTemplate ID="1" Codice="2" Descrizione="aaa" ...>
<SoggettiTemplate ID="2" Codice="3" Descrizione="bbb" ...>
...
</ElencoSoggettiTemplate>
<TOTREC>0</TOTREC>
<PAGECOUNT>0</PAGECOUNT>
</ROOT>
```

all i want to do is get all the the attribute from SoggettiTemplate, like `ID,Codice`... doing like this `var alert($(soapResponse.text()))` i can see all the structure doing like this `soapResponse.getElementsByTagName("ElencoSoggettiTemplate")` i get an `HTMLCollection` but i can't going on and the collection count gives me 0.

Comment: yes, but i prefere using Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved doing like this:

```
$.ajax({
            //web service pubblico di prova
            url: "*web service*",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "xml", 

            processData: false,

            contentType: "text/xml",

            data: soapMessage, 
            success: function(soapResponse){
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var ss= $(soapResponse);
                alert($(soapResponse).text());
                var result=$(soapResponse).find("SoggettiTemplate").text();

                $('SoggettiTemplate',ss.text()).each(function(i){
                    var ID= $(this).attr("ID");
                    var ID= $(this).attr("ID");
                    //getting the id parameter
                })



              },
              error: function (request, status, error) {
                  alert(request);
                  alert(status);
                  alert(error);
              }
          });
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to convert the XML string into a JS DOM object, then apply DOM methods to xmlDoc.

```
var xmlob = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = xmlob.parseFromString(xml_string,"text/xml");
var tags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('tag_ame');
//...traverse tags with for() instruction
```

See the tutorial from this page: http://coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-xml

It has an example with getElementsByTagName and getAttribute()

Comment: i've already seen those tutorial, my problem is that when i  do getElementsByTagName("SoggettiTemplate") i get an empty html collection

Comment: Make sure that if you're going to post reference links to your own generated content that you disclose that it is yours.